# Getting message that query has already been run

Tags: node.js, mongoose

It's been some time since I've worked with mongoose in a node api app. my recollection is that a simple findById would take the query and have a callback with an error or result, like this:

```
export const getOnePost = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    await Blog.findById(id, (err, result) => {
        if(err) res.send(err);
        if(!result) res.send('No post found');
        res.send(result);
    });
};
```

But I'm getting an error saying that the query has already been run when this executes. What am I doing wrong here?

This is a function called via get route:

```
router.get('/:id', getOnePost);
```

Node/Express api.

Comment: can you show us how you're calling this function?

Comment: can you post the error that you get

Comment: Don’t use both `await` and callback functions.